# Non homogeneous partial differential equation with constant coefficient

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve $$(D^2-D'^2-3D+3D')z=e^{x+2y}$$

Here I am able to calculate the C.F.(Complementary function)  and got it =$\phi_1(y+x)+e^{3x}\phi _2(y-x)$

Now, I am not able to find the P.I.(Particular integral) of the given PDE.

I know the following method of finding PI:

If the PDE is of the form :
$$F(D,D')z=f(x,y)$$

where, $f(x,y)=e^{ax+by}$ and $F(a,b)\ne 0$

Then PI$=\frac{1}{F(D,D')}e^{ax+by}=\frac{1}{F(a,b)}e^{ax+by} $

I don't know how to find PI if $F(a,b)=0$

P.S. In the given PDE, $a=1,b=2$ and $F(D,D')=D^2-D'^2-3D+3D'\implies F(a,b)=0$)

I have searched for this a lot but didn't find how to solve this case.

Please help!!!!!!

Comment: I found something serving as a handbook. [Here](https://www.brainkart.com/article/Partial-Differential-Equations-of-Higher-Order-With-Constant-Coefficients_6489/). Following it, the case is a triple root 1, so the CF have three terms, different to yours (check the section "Finding the complementary function" in the link). I'd reconsider it. And the case maybe can be treated as $f(x,y)$ not having any special form ("case iv" in the link).

Comment: @RafaBudría I checked the link you mentioned in your comment...but the case (iv) there is for homogeneous PDE and there is no mention of the case that I am looking for...may be I am missing something in understanding this...can you please solve this or explain with some relevant example??

Comment: I am confused. Absolutely all cases in the link are of inhomogeneous PDE.I think that the case (iv) can work

Comment: @RafaBudría The link you posted is for homogeneous PDE with constant coefficient...but the PDE, that I have asked for, is a non-homogeneous PDE with constant coefficients

Comment: Maybe now [this](http://egyankosh.ac.in/bitstream/123456789/18022/1/Unit-16.pdf) can help. In fact it contains your post as a solved exercise. I found, by considering that your PDE is factorizable, a particular solution, $-(x+1)e^{x+2y}$, The page I've linked gives $-xe^{x+2y}$ instead, simpler and from a more systematic approach.

Comment: @RafaBudría Thank you so much..:)..this new link answers my query